# how can i access the status of the data in an object element in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

good Day mates! i just want to ask if is there a possible way i can access or observe the data in an object tag/element, for example i have an html file which fetch data into an object :

```
<object data="aws.com/s3/example.pdf" ></object>
```

the main goal here is i want to make an animation Loader between the delayed time before the data is being viewed(yes viewed not fetch) in the browser. so i am thinking if i should able to get access/manipulate the data attribute maybe that's a big help. thank you

Comment: How is the data getting fetched? There are many ways of doing this, but they are more dependent on your fetch logic than your DOM. Could you maybe provide a snippet of your controller code or your service code?

Comment: fetching of the data i think is not the problem. because the DOM executed already the fetching of data from controller to the object. but before the object(pdf) getting displayed, a delay in the browser creates a a white page before the real PDF is displayed in the browser and i want to put animation between that delay